# EXC_BAD_ACESS error

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, exc-bad-access

I get that error EXC_BAD_ACESS at the following line:

```
NSString *titleVarName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"occasionTitle",i];
```

Here is the for loop where the above code line is located:

```
for (i=0; i < count; ++i) 
{

    //Save the occasionS details to NSUserDefaults

    NSString *titleVarName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"occasionTitle",i];

    NSString *dateVarName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"occasionDate",i];

    NSString *imageVarName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"occasionImage",i];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[[[self displayedObjects] objectAtIndex:i]     
title] forKey:titleVarName];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[[[self displayedObjects] objectAtIndex:i]     
date] forKey:dateVarName];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[[[self displayedObjects] objectAtIndex:i] 
imagePath] forKey:imageVarName]; 

    //release

    [titleVarName release];
    [dateVarName release];
    [imageVarName release];


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Isn't ok to alloc objects and release them inside a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%d` or `%i` specifier instead of `%@` to specify an integer. If `%@` is used with int then it will try to access the object at the address specified by the int. For example, if the value of `i` is one then it is trying to access the object at address one which will cause a bad access.

```
NSString *titleVarName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%d",@"occasionTitle",i];
```

And also you don't need `alloc` and `release` here, though that is not the reason of bad access. You can use a convenience constructor.

```
NSString *titleVarName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"occasionTitle%d", i];
// release not required
```

Do the same for `dateVarName` and `imageVarName` too.

Comment: `0` is actually the only value of `i` that _won't_ cause a bad access, because that's `nil`.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, I missed that. Fixed the example. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it and thanks for the extra tip about the convenience constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `i` is an `int`, that line should be

```
NSString *titleVarName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%i",@"occasionTitle",i];
```

`%@` is used for Cocoa objects, not primitives like an int, float or bool;

Answer (score 0):

Use the `%@` format specifier only for `NSObject` objects.

As `i` is an integer in your code, you have to use `%d` or `%i` for integers.

Moreover, there is no need to include the string using `%@`, you can use the static string directly in your format string:

```
NSString *titleVarName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"occasionTitle%i",i];
```